# How to access inner classes via an explicit namespace?

Tags: scala, inheritance, inner-classes, traits

```
trait Base
{
    val widget = new Widget {}

    trait Widget
}

trait Child1 extends Base
{
    override val widget = new Widget {}

    trait Widget extends super.Widget
}

trait Child2 extends Base
{
    override val widget = new Widget {}

    trait Widget extends super.Widget
}

class Sample extends Child1 with Child2
{
    override val widget = // Here be dragons
}
```

Is there some way to properly compose the widget in Sample? It works fine if Child1#Widget and Child2#Widget have a distinguished name, but I'm curious if it is possible to access them like this.

I'm failing with `new Child1#Widget with Child2#Widget`: "not a legal prefix for a constructor"

or

```
override val widget =
{
    val a = this: Child1
    val b = this: Child2

    new a.Widget with b.Widget {}
}
```

"illegal inheritance: inherits different type instances of trait Widget"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
class Sample extends Child1 with Child2 {
  override val widget = new Widget {}
  trait Widget extends super[Child1].Widget with super[Child2].Widget
}
```

Or just:

```
class Sample extends Child1 with Child2 {
  override val widget = new super[Child1].Widget with super[Child2].Widget {}
}
```

Comment: A sidenote to why this approach does unfortunately not work with package qualifiers: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1915